# Can't connect to a remote MySQL Database

Tags: remote, web-server, connection, mysql, database

I am running 2 Raspberry Pi3 (STRETCH, JESSIE) and a web server (PHP5, MySQL, PHPMyadmin, Apache2) on stretch. I have everything working as expected. However, I need to be able to connect to my MySQL from a remote machine to store data, but I can't connect at all. I have gone UP and DOWN the Internet looking for answers and solution and have tried them all. Still, I can't connect to the MySQL Database. I did the following after reading through Raspberry Pi forum.

`Logged into mysql and executed the following commands`

`CREATE USER 'myusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';`

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myusername'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Then, I logged out of mysql and I modified my.cnf file as follows; Commented out the following line in that file.

`sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf` and commented out `#bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

**My remote machine still can't connect to MySQL database.**

However, I did notice something. On the pi that is running the webserver, my program running on it can connect using the ip address of the machine instead of **localhost** after doing the above steps before it would only connect using localhost. So I naturally assumed that now my program should be able to connect to mysql database from any other devices on the network, but it is not the case.

So, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Why is it being closed? Is there something in the description I need to change? Can you point me to a question that is very similar with a working answer. Thank you.

Comment: I voted to close your question because it is not specific to the Raspberry Pi. IIRC without the bind_address directive MySQL won't listen for external connections.

Comment: Why aren't you running RaspiOS Buster with Mariadb 10.3 and PHP7.3? You MUST update the `bind-address` in your config from `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` so that any machine in your LAN can connect to the database? It looks like you've got that piece wrong.

Comment: @Dougie yes... for the last two days I've been trying any and/or all solutions I've come across on Raspberry Pi forums, the Internet, blogs, etc, etc, etc... Nothing seems to work. I have changed bind-address to 0.0.0.0 and tried to connect and it also failed. On one of the forum post, someone said completely COMMENT out the bind-address and it should work. As you can see... I am not able to connect.

Comment: Run `sudo netstat -tlnpu | grep mysql` to see what address it's listening on you should get `0.0.0.0:3306`. Then you just need to create a remote user as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288118/3491475

Comment: @Dougie I ran that command on terminal and got `tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:3306   0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN 1380/mysqld` Is this means mysql is listening on 1380 port for remote connection.

Comment: @Dougie and that mysql is not listening on `port 3306` as it originally suppose too?

Comment: @Dougie one more question. Do you need to also have MySQL installed on the remote machine to make the remote connection to MySQL server? I thought you don't have to.

Comment: The `0.0.0.0:3306` means it's working correctly. You do not need MySQL on the remote machine, you do need a MySQL connector or JAR file. I use SquirrelSQL as a remote client.

Comment: @Dougie yep, you are right... As it turns out the reason my program couldn't make the remote connection was because, it couldn't load any SQL library files since I didn't install any SQL. Someone on another forum said that I must install mysql on the remote machine. I did and it connects with no issues. I have heard of SquirrelSQL... I think I need look into that... Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check is that your MySQL (or more likely MariaDB) server is listening on the INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0) address. That needs a change to `bind-address 0.0.0.0` in your config file.

Then use `sudo netstat -tlnpu | grep mysql` to check that the mysqld task is running and listening OK.

Next create a remote user as per the instructions at [MySQL adding user for remote access](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288118/3491475)

Finally the remote user needs a copy of a mysql-client or a remote connector like [MariaDB Java Connector](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-java/)

Something like SquirrelSQL is a Java client (runs anywhere even on a Raspberry) that gives you a SQL dashboard (can create database, create tables and run simple or complex SQL with that). Download that from [Squirrel SQL download](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)